# Solve: $(2x+3)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(2x+3)\frac{dy}{dx}-12y=6x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $(2x+3)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(2x+3)\frac{dy}{dx}-12y=6x$

Is my equation (2) correct? Because while solving the auxiliary equation, I am not getting a 'neat' value for $m$.

[image]

Comment: Your $m$ is **correct**. Sometimes, they are not simple values.

Comment: @Moo But the solution is $y=A(2x+3)^{-1}+B(2x+3)^3-\frac{3}{4}(2x+3)+3$. This shows $m=3,-1$.

Comment: It is an ugly solution, see: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2x+%2B+3)%5E2+y%27%27+-+(2x+%2B+3)+y%27+-+12+y+%3D+6+x Also, you can test the solution you gave by substituting it into the ODE and seeing if it works.

Comment: @Moo Yes checked manually. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

You ca use this substitution as well:

Take $2x+3=t$ to get a Cauchy-Euler non homogeneous linear ODE: $$4t^2y''-2ty'-12y=6x$$

Try this!

Comment: +1 for the Euler's method

Answer (score 3):

You can use Euler 's equation like @Resident has pointed out

You can also substitute $$y=(2x+3)^m$$
Then solve the equation
$$2m^2-3m-6=0$$
$$\implies m=\frac {3 \pm \sqrt {57}}4$$
The general solution of the homogeneous equation is
$$y_h(x)=c_1(2x+3)^{\frac {3 + \sqrt {57}}4}+c_2(2x+3)^{\frac {3 - \sqrt {57}}4}$$

the particular solution is 
$$y_p=ax+b, y'_p=a, y''_p=0$$
$$-a(2x+3)-12(ax+b)=6x$$
$$\implies y_p=-\frac 37x+\frac 3 {28}$$

Comment: You made my hit generalized! +

Comment: your hint is far better ..Euler 's technique teach you much more that the one I posted .@ResidentDementor